# MapEventsReceiver Conflicts with Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-spinner, osmdroid

I am using OSMDroid and OSMBonusPack in my app.
I have a Spinner above my mapview,
the problem is that the Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener Interrupts the functionality of MapEventsReceiver making it not working. But when I remove the Spinner, everything works fine and I can implement map click listeners.

Comment: Is the spinner on top of the map or above the map?

Comment: its in a linear layout above the map oriented vertically.

Comment: You should provide your layout file.